# rewrite url to subdirectory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm new at url rewriting using appache.

I have a htaccess file with those rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^hostname/* [NC]
RewriteRule  http://hostname/subDir/*  [L,R]
```

The purpose of the rules is for rewriting the request from http://hostname to http://hostname/subDir.

I tested the rules using http://htaccess.mwl.be/ but cannot make the RewriteRule work. Tried different rules but non of them works.

Can someone help me with this simple rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what exactly do you want to achieve, but something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  =www.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subDir [NC]
RewriteRule ^ subDir%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

Comment: I need to filter using the hostname. hostname1 redirect point to http://hostname/subDir/ and hostname2 should redirect to http;//hastname/subDir2/